# cakephp debug status

Tags: debugging, cakephp

I would like to return the current debug level in a controller. The objective it to echo specific messages, when the whole app is in debug mode. If not in debug mode, it should not give the messages.

cake 2.x

Thx
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the debug() function?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html

e.g.

```
debug("Some String");
```

or

```
debug($myArray);
```

This will print debug information but only when in debug mode (level > 0)

Comment: debug mode is also level 1 btw (non-debug === 0)

Comment: My mistake I thought these were only displayed on level 2

Comment: level 2 is for more verbose output and some extra debugging in some places. but debug() behaves the same for level > 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the value of all 'Config' parameters via 'Configure::read()', *including* the current value of 'debug'; Documentation can be found here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class

You can output custom messages using this ;

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    echo '<h1>Your site is running in debug-mode</h1>';
    echo '<p>debug level: ' . Configure::read('debug') . '</p>';
}
```

If you just need to output generic 'debug' messages, use `debug('mymessage')` as suggested by @cowls